# Android private release

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, release-management

I had made some Google search about this, but I didn`t find the best solution. I hope you can help.

So I would like to release an app inside my company, we have more tha 500 employees. I found we have two solution:

-*Create a Google Company account* and release in a private channel. I would like to **IGNORE** this, because the company account has monthly fees

-*Create a Google+ Community or a Group* and release the app as an Alpha test in the Google PlayStore. It`s great, but as I see I can add people to community ONE BY ONE. Am I right, when I was ,  I have to add each of the **employees one by one** ? It could take forever.

Please mind, internal website releasing is NOT an option. We would like to use the features of GooglePlay.

So, what is the best solution from your point of view, to create an internal android release ? 
Thank you,

Comment: @metalurgus, may I kindly ask to add any link/doc about this ? I have to report to my boss, and I didn`t find anything yet

Comment: thanks mate, I think this is the best solution. can you please add it as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add people by yourself, you should give them instructions how to apply for alpha testing, and then just confirm them all in google groups.
You can follow [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) instructions. The only thing you should know that the users should apply to the google group by themselves, and you just accept their requests

Comment: since this is the best option to manage the users and use Google Play features, I would accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Publish the debug apk over internal website ( intranet site) and ask your employees to download from there.